# ios-charts hide values that are outside the bar bounds (stacked bar chart)

Tags: ios, ios-charts

The values in my charts are currently being rendered outside of their respective bars, how do I make only those values that fit the bars visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, because the sub bar's height is smaller than the value text hight.

You can override `drawValues` to filt those texts.

Comment: That sounds like a huge pain. Is there a way to simply not display any values at all then?

Comment: drawValuesEnabled = false